# scrollview not applying for the buttons in android

Tags: android, scrollview

Hi in the below xml layout I am designed a form with scollview .When I am scrolling buttons are not visibling .

I want to display buttons also when I am scrooling a form.Scrollview not applying for the complete form as well as buttons save and cancel.but save and cancel buttons are not displaying.

can any one help me where i did mistake

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/back_blue">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/below"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/account_name"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/account_name"
                        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                        android:textColorHint="#0072BA"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout" />

                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp">

                    <fr.ganfra.materialspinner.MaterialSpinner
                        android:id="@+id/ownership_type"
                        android_id="@+id/ownership_type"
                        android_layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android_layout_width="match_parent"
                        app_ms_arrowColor="#0000FF"
                        app_ms_arrowSize="16dp"
                        app_ms_floatingLabelColor="#00FF00"
                        app_ms_floatingLabelText="floating label"
                        app_ms_hint="hint"
                        app_ms_hintColor="#00FF00"
                        app_ms_multiline="true"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:ms_arrowColor="@color/black"
                        app:ms_hintColor="@color/black" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp">

                    <fr.ganfra.materialspinner.MaterialSpinner
                        android:id="@+id/facility_type"
                        android_id="@+id/facility_type"
                        android_layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android_layout_width="match_parent"
                        app_ms_arrowColor="#0000FF"
                        app_ms_arrowSize="16dp"
                        app_ms_hint="hint"
                        app_ms_hintColor="#00FF00"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:ms_arrowColor="@color/black"
                        app:ms_hintColor="@color/black" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    app:passwordToggleTint="@color/colorAccent">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/email"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/email"
                        android:inputType="number" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp">

                    <fr.ganfra.materialspinner.MaterialSpinner
                        android:id="@+id/account_manger"
                        android_id="@+id/account_manger"
                        android_layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android_layout_width="match_parent"
                        app_ms_arrowColor="#0000FF"
                        app_ms_arrowSize="16dp"
                        app_ms_hint="hint"
                        app_ms_hintColor="#00FF00"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:ms_arrowColor="@color/black"
                        app:ms_hintColor="@color/black" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    app:passwordToggleTint="@color/colorAccent">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/editMobilephone"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/custom_mobile"
                        android:inputType="number" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
                    app:passwordToggleTint="@color/colorAccent">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/bill_add"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/bill_address"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:lines="5"
                        android:maxLines="5" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
                    app:passwordToggleTint="@color/colorAccent">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/bill_city"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/bill_city"
                        android:inputType="text" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
                    app:passwordToggleTint="@color/colorAccent">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/bill_dist"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/bill_district"
                        android:inputType="text" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp">

                    <fr.ganfra.materialspinner.MaterialSpinner
                        android:id="@+id/state"
                        android_id="@+id/state"
                        android_layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android_layout_width="match_parent"
                        app_ms_arrowColor="#0000FF"
                        app_ms_arrowSize="16dp"
                        app_ms_floatingLabelColor="#00FF00"
                        app_ms_floatingLabelText="floating label"
                        app_ms_hint="hint"
                        app_ms_hintColor="#00FF00"
                        app_ms_multiline="true"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:ms_arrowColor="@color/black"
                        app:ms_hintColor="@color/black" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
                    app:passwordToggleTint="@color/colorAccent">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/bill_country"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/bill_country"
                        android:inputType="text" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
                    app:passwordToggleTint="@color/colorAccent">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/bill_pin"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/bill_pin"
                        android:inputType="text" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
                    app:passwordToggleTint="@color/colorAccent">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/website"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/bill_pin"
                        android:inputType="text" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/btnLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/save"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/save"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@color/White" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/cancel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/cancel"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: why you have so many extra layouts? Your parent relative layout and your first linear layout inside scroll view is completely useless. Also post screenshot of how your layout looks

Comment: Please make structure of your question better and pay attention to writing rules.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<RelativeLayout>

     <ScrollView>

          <LinearLayout>
               .......
          </LinearLayout>

     </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/back_blue">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/below"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnLayout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/account_name"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/account_name"
                        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                        android:textColorHint="#0072BA"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout" />

                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp">

                    <fr.ganfra.materialspinner.MaterialSpinner
                        android:id="@+id/ownership_type"
                        android_id="@+id/ownership_type"
                        android_layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android_layout_width="match_parent"
                        app_ms_arrowColor="#0000FF"
                        app_ms_arrowSize="16dp"
                        app_ms_floatingLabelColor="#00FF00"
                        app_ms_floatingLabelText="floating label"
                        app_ms_hint="hint"
                        app_ms_hintColor="#00FF00"
                        app_ms_multiline="true"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:ms_arrowColor="@color/black"
                        app:ms_hintColor="@color/black" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp">

                    <fr.ganfra.materialspinner.MaterialSpinner
                        android:id="@+id/facility_type"
                        android_id="@+id/facility_type"
                        android_layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android_layout_width="match_parent"
                        app_ms_arrowColor="#0000FF"
                        app_ms_arrowSize="16dp"
                        app_ms_hint="hint"
                        app_ms_hintColor="#00FF00"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:ms_arrowColor="@color/black"
                        app:ms_hintColor="@color/black" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    app:passwordToggleTint="@color/colorAccent">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/email"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/email"
                        android:inputType="number" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp">

                    <fr.ganfra.materialspinner.MaterialSpinner
                        android:id="@+id/account_manger"
                        android_id="@+id/account_manger"
                        android_layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android_layout_width="match_parent"
                        app_ms_arrowColor="#0000FF"
                        app_ms_arrowSize="16dp"
                        app_ms_hint="hint"
                        app_ms_hintColor="#00FF00"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:ms_arrowColor="@color/black"
                        app:ms_hintColor="@color/black" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    app:passwordToggleTint="@color/colorAccent">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/editMobilephone"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/custom_mobile"
                        android:inputType="number" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
                    app:passwordToggleTint="@color/colorAccent">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/bill_add"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/bill_address"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:lines="5"
                        android:maxLines="5" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
                    app:passwordToggleTint="@color/colorAccent">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/bill_city"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/bill_city"
                        android:inputType="text" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
                    app:passwordToggleTint="@color/colorAccent">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/bill_dist"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/bill_district"
                        android:inputType="text" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp">

                    <fr.ganfra.materialspinner.MaterialSpinner
                        android:id="@+id/state"
                        android_id="@+id/state"
                        android_layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android_layout_width="match_parent"
                        app_ms_arrowColor="#0000FF"
                        app_ms_arrowSize="16dp"
                        app_ms_floatingLabelColor="#00FF00"
                        app_ms_floatingLabelText="floating label"
                        app_ms_hint="hint"
                        app_ms_hintColor="#00FF00"
                        app_ms_multiline="true"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:ms_arrowColor="@color/black"
                        app:ms_hintColor="@color/black" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
                    app:passwordToggleTint="@color/colorAccent">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/bill_country"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/bill_country"
                        android:inputType="text" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
                    app:passwordToggleTint="@color/colorAccent">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/bill_pin"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/bill_pin"
                        android:inputType="text" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
                    app:passwordToggleTint="@color/colorAccent">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/website"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/bill_pin"
                        android:inputType="text" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/btnLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/save"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/save"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@color/White" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/cancel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/cancel"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Expected behavior for this answer

[image: Expected behavior for this answer]

If you draw the layout form you want in question, it will be easier to understand.

Comment: Don't want to scroll with the button pinned to the bottom?

Comment: pinned bottom .still buttons are not displaying

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the button outside the ScrollView.